# sklearn LabelEncoder : TypeError : '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I want to text classification using KNN algorithm. And I have data with .csv extension.
[image]

If I print with this code, the data looks like this:

```
# Preprocessing

X = np.array(dataset.iloc[:, :1])
y = np.array(dataset['Class'])

print("Data variabel X : ", X)
print("Data variabel y : ", y)
```

**Output :**

```
[['pada awalnya aku memandang gadis itu nani namanya']['dua buah melon yang subur segar']]['Pornografi''Non-Pornografi']
```

And I split for Train and Test:

```
# Train Test Split

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.20)

# loading library
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

# Feature Scaling
lb = LabelEncoder()  
lb.fit(X_train)

X_train = lb.transform(X_train)  
X_test = lb.transform(X_test)

print("X_train : ", X_train)
print("X_test : ", X_test)

# instantiate learning model (k = 3)
knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=3)

# fitting the model
knn.fit([[X_train, y_train]], [y])

# predict the response
pred = knn.predict(X_test)

# evaluate accuracy
print (accuracy_score(y_test, pred))
```

I got error message :

```
    <ipython-input-223-7d80eb4ea7d1> in <module>()
      8 
      9 X_train = lb.transform(X_train)
---> 10 X_test = lb.transform(X_test)
     11 
     12 print("X_train : ", X_train)
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'
```

Whats wrong with my code?

Comment: @user6655984 I got error in line `X_test = lb.transform(X_test)` **DataConversionWarning: A column-vector y was passed when a 1d array was expected. Please change the shape of y to (n_samples, ), for example using ravel().
  y = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)**

Comment: Can you share some of the input samples in text form as well? Makes it easier to help debugging... Also, one reason could be that your test set has a value that does not appear in the training data. Have you checked for that?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
lb.transform(X_test.astype(str))
```

Basically, you need to convert your data into **one** format.